# "[\S\s]*?" What Does This Regex Mean?

Tags: regex, vb.net, uipath, rpa

As far as I know,

- `[\S\s]` == Match Any Character,
- `*` == match any character
- `?` == optional.

What does this means?

```cs
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(getMsg,"(?<=Status         :\s+)[\S\s]*?(?=  ╙█)").Value
```

The input that the regex is used on is:

```
"Status : ******** "
```

Comment: In short "?" here is not an optional parameter but part of ["lazy quantifier"](https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#lazy-mode)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct on the first assessment - [\S\s] will match any character - INCLUDING whitespaces and linebreaks. The second assessment isn't *technically* correct - the asterisk wildcard symbol means that it will match zero or more of the preceding token, so in combination with the first part, yes will mean 'match any character'.

? in RegEx does not mean 'optional'. It means:
`Makes the preceding quantifier lazy, causing it to match as few characters as possible. By default, quantifiers are greedy, and will match as many characters as possible.` (Source: https://regexr.com/). This essentially will negate the asterisk quantifier and will mostly cause unexpected results - use '*' and '?' together with caution.

Along with the preceding \s+ token used - there is a little too much going on in this RegEx. Check out https://regexr.com/ and use this as an always tool when employing RegEx. This site not only explains every aspect of a RegEx, but also lets you test your current expression to see if a test expression matches.